# What factors make a good team for competitive triples in Pokemon X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am done with the Elite four and have spent some time battling in the Battle Maison. Now I would like to start battling online competitively.

I'd like to build a team around the triples battle format. How can I build a good triples team with Pokemon from X And Y, including Megas? What factors should I consider when composing my team?

Comment: This will depend on various factors - What battle format are you aiming to play? (Singles, Doubles, Triples, Rotation battles etc). How much do you know about setting up competitive Pokemon? (Breeding, IVs, EVs, Moves etc). Have you battled in the Battle Maison before? What style of team are you looking for? Pokemon that inflict status and stall out the opponent?  Pokemon that work well together, or are good individually with little in the way of team cohesion?

Comment: triple battle with good team Pokemon and I have been in battle mason before

Comment: thanks, I have edited your question slightly to reflect that. I haven't spent a whole lot of time with triples (I'm more proficient in double battles) - but generally, look at Pokemon that can intimidate  (like Mawhile), Pokemon that can redirect attacks (like Amoonguss with Rage Powder), Weather starters (like Mega Charizard Y or Tyranitar) and try to build a 'core' around two or so key Pokemon. I'll try and write up a full answer later when I have more time.

Comment: These forum threads might be useful: https://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/battle-spot-triples-metagame-discussion.3533914/ https://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/battle-spot-triples-viability-rankings.3549201/ But keep in mind triples hasn't been officially supported in the games since gen 6, so finding players to battle against might be difficult. Might I recommend doubles instead?

Comment: If you haven't tried it before I highly recommend testing your team out in showdown. It's a great battle simulator with a nice team builder. https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/

Comment: @Quinn Showdown is great, but following Pyritie's comment, I don't believe Showdown supports triple battles

Comment: @Wondercricket woops, for some reason I thought he was asking about doubles - that's my bad. Could still be useful for the team builder alone.

Comment: A lof of the tips for competitive Doubles can be applied to Triples. And it's much easier to find tips for Doubles online than Triples.